# App Shortcuts missing in Keyboard preferences

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings

I upgraded to Mavericks recently and it seems I am now missing the ability to set App Shortcuts. I only see the following in my Keyboard/Shortcuts preferences. Any thoughts on how to get App Shortcuts back?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag the divider bar to the right to show the categories.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. This was really such a simple answer. Apple should put a bit of instruction text at the bottom or make the slider more obvious for eye-strained users.